# How to make eww default browser in Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, eww

When I click on links in my org-mode buffer it opens up my external browser. How can I make Emacs default to eww (and let me open up an external browser from there if I wish)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As noted in the [EWW info manual node](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/EWW.html) you can use EWW as a target for [browse-url](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Browse_002dURL.html#Browse_002dURL), which is what Org uses if a URI starts with "http", "https", etc. You can of course customize browse-url behaviour with `M-x customize-group browse-url`

Alternatively, add the following to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`: `(setq browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url)`

If you're visiting a webpage in EWW you can hit `&` `(eww-browse-with-external-browser)` to open the page in an external browser.

Comment: Can you give me some more information how to manipulate `browse-url`? `browse-url-browser-function` is set to `browse-url-default-browser` which itself appears to just be a symbol, not a variable. How do I actually set eww as the default browser? Following the info documentation you linked to doesn't actually describe how to do this afaic.

Comment: If you use the "customize" interface to edit `browse-url-browser-function`, you'll find a convenient drop-down menu of values, including "eww" which results in it setting `eww-browse-url` as the function.

Answer (score -1):

I set firefox as my default browser with

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "firefox")
```

I can't test it with `eww` because I'm on Emacs 24.3.1 -- but this might work (perhaps with a modification -- since `eww` seems to be an emacs package, instead of an external program).